# Extracting server names from emails in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I want to extract the server name from  a string using Substring. I am not sure if I should iterate a loop or with `StringTokenizer`, `indexof`, `lastindex` or what ever.

Basic requirement is, I should use `substring()`

For example:

```
 id@yahoo.com  ,  my@gmail.com etc
```

This goes in paragraph  and should print server names like this:

```
Server names: yahoo,   gmail ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String emails = "id@yahoo.com  ,  my@gmail.com ,  luigi@microsoft.com";
emails = emails.trim();  // get rid of spaces.
String[] parts = emails.split(",");  // emails array.

for (String email : parts) 
{
    String temp = email.substring(email.indexOf("@") + 1); // e.g. @google.com
    String serverName = temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf("."));  // e.g. google
    System.out.println(serverName);  //prints google
}
```

**Sample Runs (for single inputs):**

**Input:** mario@google.com  **Output**: google

**Input:** alvaro.arbeloa@realmadrid.com  **Output**: realmadrid

**Input:** luigi@forest.yahoo.com  **Output**: forest

**EDIT:** If your emails are not separated with commas or any other delimiters, then you can extract individual e-mail addresses with this code:

```
String emails = "id@yahoo.com    my@gmail.com";
String[] parts = emails.split("\\s+");
```

Denote that I'm not using `trim()` this time. After this splitting, you can again use the same for-loop above.

Comment: thanks , i am  doing it for more than one email , i mean  in a paragraph    that contains just email addresses    like   sample@gmail.com   sample@yahoo.com   sample@hotmail.com   .. plz help  in this regard  if i should iterate a loop for array or something else ,

Comment: yes it works for that  but  if  input is  like this     id@gmail.com   Id@yahoo.com  id@hotmail  and so on a complete paragraph ... so

Comment: yes , it works .. Thanks a lot for immediate help  u really  made it easy for me .    Thanks

Comment: can we do something in this style                                 for(i=0; i<email.length; i++)    { samples[i]... } i mean iterate over   array  in for loop like this .. i know it has been solved just want to ask for clarification  , Thanks in advance

Comment: @Sikander of course you can. the for loop i have used in my answer is called enhanced for loop.

Comment: can u please  help me in this  way ..  enhanced for loop  is   bit tricky for me as i am beginner , everything else is quite  ok

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
   String temp = parts[i].substring(parts[i].indexOf("@") + 1);
   String serverName = temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf("."));
   System.out.println(serverName);
  }`

Comment: Hello , can u please explain  This a bit ?     "\\s+"   that was used with split  . Thanks .

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that this is a homework, here are a few points that should get you there:

- The substring that you are looking for starts one character after the `@` sign
- The server name ends with the first dot `.` in the string
- You take a substring with (you guessed it right!) the `substring(from,to)` method
- The first index in `substring` is inclusive; the second indes is not inclusive
- You find the index of a character by using `indexOf('x')` method, substituting `x` for the character that you search